# Could the classical Ramsey numbers be successors of primes?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, intuition, meta-math

Let $R(n)$ denote the classical Ramsey-number, that is, the smallest natural $N$, for which every blue-red edge-colouring of $K_N$ admits a monochromatic $K_n$.

Consider the conjecture: $R(n)-1$ is prime for all $n\geq 3$.

Obviously, there is little to support the conjecture because we only know $R(3)=6$, $R(4)=18$ and that $R(5)=44$ (or, less likely, $R(5)=48$) is not impossible. However, maybe there is some value in asking whether there is some evidence against the conjecture, that is, is there some conceptual, heuristic etc. reason why the above is an unreasonable guess other than the mere scarcity of data?

Comment: You may want to note that $R(5)$ could be any value from 44 to 48...

Comment: Is there even a reason why it should be even?

Comment: @TravisJ I'm not saying it couldn't, I'm saying the range of possible values for $R(5)$ does not invalidate the conjecture.

Comment: @DamianReding, ok, I see your point.  I think it is very, very unlikely that there is any connection.  The problem with looking at only a few examples (2) is that you can draw almost any conclusion you want.  In addition, the primes are more dense in the smaller integer range, so more numbers are likely to be close to a prime there.

Comment: I would start with @MeesdeVries observation and ask: is there any reason that $R(n)$ should always be even?  If not, then it certainly can't be 1 more than a prime.

Comment: Have the possibilities $R(5) = 43,49$ been ruled out?  I guess this is a different question, but a reference as to why $R(5)=44$ is considered "likely" would be interesting.

Comment: No, they haven't as far as I know. I was just referring to those two candidates for R(5), which are implied by the conjecture.